# Alarm when time reaches zero

Tags: javascript

The problem I have here is when I try to implement the audio is that it keeps on playing every second, I have included the source for the audio code at the very bottom if you may need it.

````
let time = startingMinutes * 60;

const countdownEl = document.getElementById('Countdown');


setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);

function updateCountdown () {
    const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    let seconds = time % 60;

    seconds = seconds <10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

    countdownEl.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;

    time--;
    time = time < 0 ? 0 : time; 
    
    
}

const audio = new Audio();
audio.src = "alarm.mp3"; ```
````

Comment: When else did you expect the audio to start playing and why…?

Comment: Hi. Question is not clear. Do you want to run the Audio only once, when counter reaches 0?

Comment: @dr_sunshine yes I want the audio to only run when the counter reaches 0

Comment: @deceze I simply want the audio to play when the counter reaches 0

Comment: Then you need to do that when `time <= 0`, not right after starting the interval.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear setInterval once timer reaches 0 and also need to put the audio code inside updateCountdown function when timer reaches 0. Additionally you can use a global variable to track if audio is played or not and use it conditionally. Check the code.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    
    let startingMinutes = 1; // one min
    let time = startingMinutes * 60;

    var audioPlayed = false; // audio is not played - create a global variable to track if audio is already played (optional)
    const countdownEl = document.getElementById('Countdown');

    const counterInterval = setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);

    function updateCountdown () {
        const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
        let seconds = time % 60;

        seconds = seconds <10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

        countdownEl.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;

        time--;
        time = time < 0 ? 0 : time;
        
        if(!time && !audioPlayed) {
            
            const statusEl = document.getElementById('Status');
            
            var status = "timer reaches 0";
            
            // prefered - clear interval, so once timer reaches zero, there will be no more call to updateCountdown
            clearInterval(counterInterval);
            status += ", clear setInterval";

            // this is optional, in case the code above not work for any reason
            // set the global var audioPlayed to true to indicate audio is played
            audioPlayed = true;
                    
            status += ", audio play starts";
            
            Status.innerHTML = status;
            
            // run your audio
            // const audio = new Audio();
            // audio.src = "alarm.mp3";
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<html>
    <span id="Countdown"></span> &nbsp; <span id="Status"></span>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the people viewing this question and would like an answer. Please note this audio will keep on playing as the timer stays at 0

```
const startingMinutes= 1;
let time = startingMinutes * 60;

const countdownEl = document.getElementById('Countdown');


setInterval(updateCountdown, 1000);

function updateCountdown () {
    const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    let seconds = time % 60;

    seconds = seconds <10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;

    countdownEl.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;

    time--;
    time = time < 0 ? 0 : time; 
    if (time <=0) {audio.play()};
    
}

const audio = new Audio();
audio.src = "alarm.mp3";
```

Comment: Hi Donut .. I've posted the answer with the solution. Did you get a chance to check it?